# Elementary Q: In Ride interface, in text edit tab, the search text field doesn't work. Is it the same for you?

Tags: robotframework-ide

I hope that someone responds to very elementary questions as well as the difficut ones. It's more than oe months that i use Ride for RobotFramework and i could never use the Search button on Text editor tab of Ride.
i write a word (not keyword) and i click the search button ( not Apply Changes button) and nothing happens. is it normal?

Thanks for any insight

Answer (score 0):

The Search Button expects to have the text box on its left filled with the words to search.

You can also select the text and press Ctrl-G that will fill the text box an start the search (from the top of the file). Shift-Ctrl-G does the same but backwards.

This is a very rudimentary search function, but allows to find and replace if you have previously put content in memory (Ctrl-C), you can Search and then Ctrl-V.